# linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Tags: kernel

I'm running Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-53-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory: 62.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2

I get the following error regardless of what I attempt to install or update.

```
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic (--configure):
installed linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I've tried:

- apt clean
- apt upgrade

It doesn't boot unless I use the previous kernel.
uname -a: (Prompt info removed below for privacy)
5.15.0-53-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

What am I missing?
I'm not the most savvy command line user.
This all began after a kernel update in Discover.